# How to Edit MSWord documents in an iPad application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ms-word

There appears to be iPad applications that can edit MSWord documents such as "Pages".  My question is how can this be accomplished programmatically?  Are these apps using OpenXML to do this or is there another way to do it.  An API or something?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These applications such as Pages use private code to read documents and edit it. At this time there is no OpenXML library for the iPhone SDK. The iOS provides a way to display documents (doc, ppt, xls, pdf) by using the UIWebView but no other API.

Developing a word editor is a real challenge, we did a small rich text editor and it was a very interesting project.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can now show a button which will allow the user to press it and send the document to another app for editing, the list of apps the file can be sent to is managed by Apple code, so you don't have to do much. Google "ios document controller"

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in the app we may be developing, the editing must be done programmatically.